# Find file name of any deletions in a branch since it was created

Tags: bash, git

**Question**

Is there a better way to find the file name of any deletions in a branch since it was created?

**Example**:

If I create a new branch

```
git checkout -b "branch04"
```

add files

```
echo '1.txt 2.txt 3.txt' | xargs touch
git add -A && git commit -m "add files"
```

I am currently getting the first commit from this branch as follows:

```
FIRSTHASH=$(git cherry main -v | head -n 1 | awk '{print $2}')
```

if I then delete a file and commit

```
rm 1.txt

git add -A && git commit -m "delete 1.txt"
```

I can get the deleted files using git log

```
git log $FIRSTHASH...HEAD --diff-filter=D --summary | grep "delete mode 100" | cut -c 21-

1.txt
```

I would prefer to not use `cut` and `grep` if there is a git native way to find any deletions in a branch since it was created.

Comment: Unclear what the problem is. `git log --compact-summary --oneline --diff-filter=D` will list just the commits in which a file was deleted and will tell you its name, if you just want the info in easy human-readable form.

Comment: @matt Nice your suggestion removes the requirement to use `cut` and I can use `git log $FIRSTHASH...HEAD --compact-summary --oneline --diff-filter=D | grep gone | awk '{print $1;}'` instead.  Apologies if unclear.  I'm simply looking for the cleanest way to find the file name of any deletions in a branch since the branch was created.  My approach appears to work but I thought there may be cleaner approaches.

Comment: Right, if you really want to filter out the other useful info such as what commit this happened in, sure, using grep is up to you.

Comment: I'm trying to build a list of deleted files.

Comment: fwiw, if you're going to pull `awk` into the mix then you can typically use `awk` to replace `grep`, `cut` and `head` though depending on what you're doing you may end up doing a bit more typing (for a comparable `awk` solution - likely not an issue if putting code in a script or function) ... upside may be a small improvement in speed from reducing the number of pipes/subprorcesses

Comment: Ok, well so have you built it?

Comment: Branches do not really have creation events. A branch name is simply a way to name a particular commit. Each *commit* has a creation event, after which it simply continues to exist. What you want here is the merge base, as in [TTT's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71453382/1256452).

Answer (score 0):

If you can trust your calculated first hash, then I'm thinking:

```
git diff $FIRSTHASH...HEAD --diff-filter=D --name-only
```

Presumably `$FIRSTHASH` is in the branch, so you can use either 2 dots or 3 dots there and get the same result.

If you know the branch you came off of, you could probably skip the `$FIRSTHASH` part. For example, if you branched from `origin/main`, then:

```
git diff origin/main...HEAD --diff-filter=D --name-only
```

Note the 3 dots in that command, which enables you to use the starting branch which is likely ahead of from where you branched. This will start from the merge-base between the two commits, instead of the 2 dot syntax which is a full diff of both sides.